# The Haml form tag includes nothing on Rails 3

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

I think there may be a bug in Haml? Or something I missed
The form tag supposed to enclose the input element, but it doesn't.

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/remote_focus/kill_running_task" data-remote="true" method="get"></form>
            <tr>
              <td>...
```

Where I expect it is

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/remote_focus/kill_running_task" data-remote="true" method="get">
                <tr>
                  <td>...
</form>
```

This is my haml file, iterate each task from an array,

```
  - @running_tasks.each do |running_task|        
    = form_tag kill_running_task_remote_focus_path, :method => :get, remote: true do
      %tr
        %td
          = running_task[:user]
        %td 
          = running_task[:ip]
        %td 
          = running_task[:time]
        %td 
          = running_task[:pid]
          = hidden_field_tag :task, running_task[:pid]
        %td
          = submit_tag "Kill This Task" ,:class=> "btn btn-primary autotest"
```

Comment: Looks okay. Try surround the form_tag arguments with `()` before `do` ? Also try not including those tds but the submit tag only? Which means putting your form_tag in last td.

Comment: Side note, use `method: :delete` if the form is supposed to delete something, not `get`.

Comment: How are you viewing the generated code? Note that nesting `tr`s directly in a `form` is not valid HTML. If you are viewing the source with the inspector of a browser you will see the DOM as it is after the browser has “fixed” it. Make sure you are looking at the actual source to see what is being generated, and make sure it is valid.

Comment: Hi @matt you should reply your suggestion as the answer. Because your solution works for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than form, a simpler tag is `button_to` or `link_to`. UJS will convert those with `remote: true` and `method: :delete` to form automatically. So

```
// Remove the previous form_tag
%td
  = button_to kill_running_task_remote_focus_path, :method => :delete, remote: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove all the **tr td** and lets try once.